# matlab array assignment

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying to save all the files in a directory as an array of strings, like this:

`files = {'hello.gdf'; 'hello2.gdf'...; ... 'etc.gdf'}`

Since I have many directories, I want to do this automatically. This is my code:

```
gdffiles = dir(fullfile('D:', 'subject', '01', '*.gdf'))
for i=1:size(gdffiles)
    files(i) = gdffiles(i).name;
end
```

I want to assign to `files` the name of the gdf files found, but I get this message:

`??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`

`Error in ==> getFiles at 3
    files(i) = gdffiles(i).name;`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason for error:**

You try to assign `files` in the `i`-th place a string (`char` array) `gdffiles(i).name`. However, you are using an array-element assignment (round parenthesis `()`). Therefore, you get an error: You can only assign a **single** `char` using `files(i)`.

**Possible solutions:**

1. You should assign to `files` using curly braces - since `files` is a `cell` array:

   ```
   files{i} = gdffiles(i).name;
   ```
2. You can achieve the same result without the loop by:

   ```
   files = { gdffiles(:).name };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution

```
path       = fullfile('D:', 'subject', '01', '*.gdf');
files      = dir(path);
files      = struct2cell(files);
files      = files( 1, 1:end );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
ListOfAllFiles = ls('*.gif')
```

Hope it helps